# Setting image to UITableViewCell background does not work correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set image as 'UITableView`cell background.I create`UIiImageView`in`cellforRowAt` func and add to cell as subView, but the result is :

[image]

It is ok only for first cell . My code in `cellForRowAt` function :

```
 let imageView =  UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x - 10  , y: cell.frame.origin.y - 20 , width: cell.frame.size.width + 20 , height: cell.frame.size.height ))
 let image = UIImage(named: "sentimg")
 imageView.image = image
 cell.backgroundView = UIView()
 cell.backgroundView!.addSubview(imageView)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `cell.bounds` instead of `cell.frame` in `let imageView =  UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x - 10  , y: cell.frame.origin.y - 20 , width: cell.frame.size.width + 20 , height: cell.frame.size.height ))`, `cell.frame` will refer the position for the cell in his superView while `cell.bounds` will refer the position relative to itself, that is what you need because you are adding your Image as cell subview

**something like this**

```
 let imageView =  UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: cell.bounds.origin.x - 10  , y: cell.bounds.origin.y - 20 , width: cell.bounds.size.width + 20 , height: cell.bounds.size.height ))`
```

Comment: That Worked ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or better yet, use autolayout constraints:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "sentimg"))
let backgroundView = UIView()
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.leftAnchor, constant: -10),
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.rightAnchor, constant: 10),
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.topAnchor, constant: -20),
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
    ])

cell.backgroundView = backgroundView
```